# Send SMS on click from users to another users on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, button, onclick, click, sms

We have wordpress that we using on our company, and we are about 20 useres. 
All users has a page with their informasjon and project prosess. We want to have a smal button to lett the users to send him/her a SMS.

Example: Tom, and Frank are both the users. Tom going to Frank page, after at Tommy tried to call Frank several times with no response from him. So he goes to Frank's side where there is a small button that let Tommy to click on it, then send an SMS from Tommy to Frank that Tells Frank at Tommy wants to have a discussion on phone with Frank.

Comment: Have you subscribed to a SMS sending service or have you bought a GSM/CDMA gateway for start? Both usually come with samples on how to invoke their APIs.

Comment: We haven't bought yet, we want to find out which Gateway or subscribed should we use for this questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you go with SMS gateway that has a REST API so you intregrate it easily with your wordpress site. One such Sms gateway is clickatell it has a very easy api that you can integrate with your   site in a few hours and its very reasonable as well.

Comment: Thanks, but we can make it only users can send SMS, I mean only registrert users?

Comment: Yes you can do that but that is something that is wordpress related  you will have to check user session and then show the button.